# Show the result of the dropdown selected value after the clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, select

I need to set up a simple list box that shows a result on the same page after the button is pressed. For example, the code below shows a list of the 7 days with times for each day. Right now when the button is pressed, I get a pop up saying "The page at "**.com" says: 7-9".

How can I have the result simply display "7-9" below the button, without a pop-up?

```
<script>
function displayResult()
{
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Select a day:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="8-8">Monday</option>
  <option value="7-9">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="7-9">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="7-9">Thursday</option>
  <option value="7-10">Friday</option>
  <option value="10-10">Saturday</option>
  <option value="10-5">Sunday</option>
</select>
</form>    
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Display result</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78NKt/

Comment: You don't want alert right? you want to show/display that `7-7` on same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way using  [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) and [function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to have the context inside the function set as that of the element itself. And additionally you can just get the value of select using `element.value` (much shorter):

```
   function displayResult() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(x.value), this.nextSibling);
    }
```

and

```
 <button type="button" onclick="displayResult.call(this)">Display result</button>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pNKSy/)**

Comment: Hey PSL, I see that the results do not refresh after a second click. The displayed values just keep accumulating next to each other.

Comment: @MaxZeygelshefer In that case wrap it in another element and do like this http://jsfiddle.net/dKQ9W/